# Can make a Styled Map for only a region instead of the whole map in Google Maps v3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-styling

I have been reading everything I can to find out how this can be done. It looks like the styled map applies only to the whole map, and I can't find a way to only apply it to a certain polygon region.

Comment: Everything is possible! You can do it dynamically, apply the style when the user pans into the area of interest and remove it when he pans out of it. What styles do you want to apply to where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible using the styled map. You'll need to supply your own overlay.

The documentation is quite useful: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished it by drawing polygon on the map and then setting it's various display properties. You can do the same as I did. There are Polygons, Circles etc etc.
You can even consider using heatmaps. Hope this is what you were asking for.
The link provided by ScottE is perfect.